# Django - solving a possible n + 1 problem

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

One of my views is hitting the db a lot with a particular query.  Scout-apm identifies it as a possible n+1 query. I'm not sure that is the problem, but it is a problem nonetheless.

My original code was:

```
models.py

class Grade(models.Model):

    score = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    testing = models.ForeignKey(Testing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Purpose, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_created = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=timezone.now)

Class Testing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    omit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
Class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    

views.py
def allgrades(request, student_id):
    classrooms = Classroom.objects.all()
    for c in classrooms:
        q = Grade.objects.filter(
            student=student_id, classroom=c.id, testing__omit="False").order_by('-time_created')
        if q.exists():
            if len(q) < 3:
                qn = q.first()
            else:
                ....
```

The offending queries come from the `if q.exists():` and `qn = q.first()`. I don't know if this falls in the category of n + 1, but the number of queries decreases from around 1300 to around 400 if I get rid of the `if q.exists():` and `qn = q.first()`

I need the functionality of these statements.  Since I'm doing something with `q`, I need to check that it exists. And as the code shows, I may want to only include the newest object.

Is there a less expensive way to deal with this?

Comment: why to iterate over all the class Rooms? can you explain Requirements pls?

Comment: Each classroom will have a different set of grades.  When the template displays this view, the user will see the grades for each classroom.

Answer (score 2):

You are making additional calls with every loop through a classroom. The first is .exists(), which is low cost to see if there is something there, but becomes a bit redundant if there is and you need to call it, as retrieving the actual record is another call (so that's up to  2 * num_classrooms).

If you prefetch everything you don't need to make many additional calls at all:

```
#set up your grade queryset for clarity
grade_queryset = Grade.objects.filter(
    student=student_id, testing__omit="False"    
).order_by('-time_created')

#get all the Classrooms and their associated grades
classrooms = Classroom.object.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'grade_set', 
        queryset=grade_queryset,
    )
 )
#now loop through - django should use its cache for .all() 
for c in classrooms:
    c_grades_count = len(c.grade_set.all())
    if c_grades_count  < 3:
        qn = c.grades.all()[0]
```

Comment: Also `classroom=c.id, ` should not be on the `grade_queryset`?

Comment: For some reasons other than database issues I need to change my view quite a bit. Should I edit this post or create a new one?In terms of this one, does `classrooms = Classroom.object.prefetch_related(Prefect('grades', queryset=grade_queryset,))` work? I tried this and got an error that `'grades' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`, same goes for grade. I wonder if this is because it's on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: try 'grade_set'.  Or you could give a related_name ='grades' to the classroom field in Grade.